# z_star calculated via scipy can grow to infinty - Is this right?

Tags: confidence-interval, inference

After years of "abstinence" I dabble back into statistics of population proportions and have some trouble making sense of critical values $z^\star$ for high confidence levels:

The critical value $z^\star$ is needed for the calculation of confidence intervals. I compute $z^\star$ from the confidence level *cl* with the Python module `scipy` via

```
cdf = 0.5+cl/2
z_star = scipy.stats.norm.ppf(cdf)
```

This `z_star` (i.e. $z^\star$) can grow to infinity, because

```
scipy.stats.norm.ppf(1)
```

outputs `inf`.

On the other hand, I'd say the confidence interval

> $CI= \hat p \pm z^\star se(\hat p)$

can reasonably not exceed $[0\%,100\%]$.

How do these things fit together?

- Is the `scipy` calculation an approximation with goes astray for confidence levels close to $100\%$?
- Or is my idea that confidence intervals not exceed $[0\%,100\%]$ not general enough?
- Or is something with my `cdf` calculation wrong?

I would love some pointers here!

Comment: The confidence level has to be between 0 and 100, but the confidence interval can be any interval.

Comment: Why can the CI be any interval? I'd say CI can be maximally [0%,100%]. Then it captures _always_  the population proportion $p$ and therefor  CI=[0%,100%]  gives us a confidence level cl =1, doesn't it?

Comment: Oops, I hadn’t noticed that it’s a proportion.

Comment: @Dave My bad. Added this crucial bit of information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end there you're using a normal approximation to a binomial proportion to obtain a confidence interval. The normal is continuous and has an infinite range while the binomial proportion is discrete and has a finite range; if you go sufficiently far into the tail of the normal you can go outside the possible range of the binomial parameter, $p$.

As the Wikipedia article [Binomial proportion confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval) puts it:

> A commonly used formula for a binomial confidence interval relies on approximating the distribution of error about a binomially-distributed observation, $\hat p$, with a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). This approximation is based on the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) and is unreliable when the sample size is small or the success probability is close to 0 or 1.

Here's an illustration of the problem:

[image: plot of cdf of the binomial(10,0.1) proportion, X/10 with normal approximation with the same mean and variance, showing a distinct amount of the left tail of the normal below 0]

If that occurs, you're outside the region of values for $p$ and $n$ where the approximation is good for those percentiles. Indeed you would usually want to stay a fair way from the 0/1 endpoints (a fairly large distance in terms standard errors of the proportion, though the absolute distance from the end might be small in a large sample)

Comment: Thanks for this. Your pointer helped me to read up on it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval), etc. It makes sense now.

Comment: Sorry to lose your suggested edit: I was editing it myself at the same time and posting my edit meant yours was lost. I will put your edit in, though. (Edit: now done)

Comment: No problem. Your graph helps *a lot*! Thanks!